# How to get Column Comments in JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, database, oracle, jdbc

I want to fetch Column comments using JDBC Metadata , But everytime it returns null , I tested with Oracle and SqlServer both cases it returning Null.

```
DatabaseMetaData dmt = con.getMetaData();    
colRs = dmt.getColumns(null, "dbo", 'Student', null);
while (colRs.next()) {
System.out.println(colRs.getString("REMARKS");
   }
```

While i am getting all other data like column name , length etc absolutely ok ...

Comment: And you're sure the comments are in a column named "REMARKS"?

Comment: @Kayaman yes .. as JavaDoc also says that  REMARKS column in metadata resultset may return Null , but not described why ....

Comment: You have to put  property `remarksReporting=true` to driverManager or  execute `((OracleConnection)conn).setRemarksReporting(true)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For Oracle you need to provide a connection property `remarksReporting` and set that to `true` or call the method `setRemarksReporting()` to enable that.

```
OracleConnection oraCon = (OracleConnection)con;
oraCon.setRemarksReporting(true);
```

After that, `getColumns()` will return the column (or table) comments in the `REMARKS` column of the ResultSet.

See [Oracle's JDBC Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/oraperf.htm#JJDBC28785) for more details

---

For SQL Server this is not possible at all.

Neither the Microsoft nor the jTDS driver expose table or column comments. Probably because there is no SQL support for that in SQL Server. The *usual* approach of using "extended properties" and the property name MS_DESCRIPTION is not reliable. Mainly because there is no requirement to us `MS_DESCRIPTION` as the property name. Not even `sp_help` returns those remarks. And at least the jTDS driver simply calls `sp_help` go the the table columns. I don't know what the Microsoft driver does.

The only option you have there, is to use `fn_listextendedproperty()` to retrieve the comments:

e.g.:

```
SELECT objname, cast(value as varchar(8000)) as value 
FROM fn_listextendedproperty ('MS_DESCRIPTION','schema', 'dbo', 'table', 'Student', 'column', null)
```

You need to replace `MS_DESCRIPTION` with whatever property name you use to store your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the getColumns() method from DatabaseMetaData does not retrieve the column comments/remarks by default for Oracle database. To fetch column comments in Oracle, you need to query the ALL_COL_COMMENTS view:

```
  // Query comments 
  String sql = "SELECT column_name, comments FROM all_col_comments WHERE table_name = ?";
  PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
  ps.setString(1, tableName);

  ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
  while (rs2.next()) {
    String name = rs2.getString("column_name");
    String comment = rs2.getString("comments");
  }
```